# Editing a Hex Stream in VBA Before Saving to File

Tags: excel, hex, hexdump, vba

**Background:** I am extracting a file that is saved in a SQL database using an ADODB connection. One column of the database is the filename, including the file extension, and another is the actual contents of the file as a hex stream. I would like to save this file and open it.

**Problem:** This works fine with .pdf files. However, with .png files there is an error- the file is corrupted when I try to open it. I used a hex editor (HxD) and noticed that there were excess values. If I remove these the file opens fine. The hex stream should begin with the "per mille" character (Chr(137) in excel) in order for the file to open. I have not found a way to edit the hex stream in excel without converting it to characters.

The .png file opens with no problem when I take out the first few characters using a hex editor so that the file begins with:

`‰PNG`

Or the equivalent in hex code:

```
89 50 4E 47
```

The excess characters are

```
ÿþ
```

Or the equivalent in hex code:

```
FF FE
```

(I am trying to remove these). These characters are in the saved file even when I remove 4 characters from the text string using

```
Content = Right(Content, Len(Content) - 4)
```

It's almost like they automatically get added before the string when I save the file.

**Code:**

Calling the save to file function, where Content is the file content and Name is the filename:

```
Call StringToTextFile("C:\", rst![Content], rst![Name])
```

The function is below:

```
Public Sub StringToTextFile(ByVal directory As String, ByVal Content As String, ByVal filename As String)
'Requires reference to scrrun.dll
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

If Right(filename, 4) = ".png" Then         'recognizing the .png file
'Content = CByte(Chr(137)) & Right(Content, Len(Content)) 'unsuccessful attempt at inserting "per mille" character
'iret = InStr(0, Chr(137), Content, vbBinaryCompare)  'unsuccessful attempt at finding the "per mille" character in the content

End If

Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(directory & filename, True, True)
ts.Write Content
ts.Close

Dim myShell As Object
Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myShell.Run directory & filename          'Open the saved file

End Sub
```

When I try to insert the "per mille" character using Chr(137) it just shows a blank space in the hex editor.

Any help is appreciated!

This seems to be a similar discussion, but I am unsure how to apply this to my case:
[excel-vba-hex-to-ascii-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809267/excel-vba-hex-to-ascii-error?rq=1)

Comment: To insert the "per mille" character try: `Content =Chr(137) & Content`

Comment: If I do this it adds a "0 " to the code (zero and space), 30 20 in hex. But it gets added AFTER the excess characters (after FF FE). I think the issue is the conversion between hex and Unicode characters. Should I be working with CByte() and ByteArray?